# Button In the Footer of ListView View Does Not Receive Events after the ListView is scrolled

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a listview with each row containg a check box and text. I have successfully added an "Answer" button to the footer of the list view that recives events and puts up a toast message saying You Clicked the save button. The problem is if the list view is scrollable and I scroll the list view up and down a couple of times, the Answer button in the footed is no longer active (at least in the emulator).  The behavior seems to be that the button does not respond to any events at all.  However, checking/unchecking the check box in the list view item will cause the setOnClickListener event of the Answer button to fire.

```
View footer = View.inflate(this,R.layout.footer, null);
getListView().addFooterView(footer,null, true); 
Button btnAnswer = (Button)footer.findViewById(R.id.btnAnswer);

btnAnswer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(View v) 
{
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," You clicked Save button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

ListViews "re-use" child views for each list item to save on memory consumption, time, etc instead of recreating new views for each item. You're setting the OnClickListener; however, when you scroll around the footer view is getting repurposed for another list item and therefore the OnClickListener is invalid.

You'll need to extend your ListAdapter and override the getView method in which you'll want to check for the footer view and set the appropriate listener if it is.

Something like:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, R.layout.list_item, strings) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Unless you want to set each child views individually, call
        // the super
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Check if it's the footer view
        if(position == this.getCount() - 1) {
            // Set the listener here
        }

        return convertView;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your button is competing for focus with the listview... listview is winning... each view (listview and your button) are fighting for focus since they have the same type of listener .... you'll have to switch to setOnTouchListener for the button to get it to work and use onClickListener for the listview

for example using anonymous class:

```
 yourfooterButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                //your response code 
                    }
               }
     });
```

There is one more alternative and its to set the following on the footer.  There is another method overload created but it did not come up in the docs, i had to check online documentation:

```
 mylistView.addFooterView(footerView, null, **false**);
```

where false tells the footer its not selectable.  I tested this myself and the buttons inside the footer respond to touches now.  I hope this an acceptable answer.

Comment: Changing from **false** to **true**, made it clickable. Thanks!